# Facebook FQL for ordered link_stats

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve an ordered (descending) result set of link_stats for urls that begin with a common substring.  I'm trying to use the following:

```
SELECT url,
       normalized_url,
       share_count,
       like_count,
       comment_count,
       total_count,
       commentsbox_count,
       comments_fbid,
       click_count
FROM   link_stat
WHERE  substr(url, 0, 22) = "http://www.example.com";
```

but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column.
```

Any advice on how to get this working ALONG with the additional syntax to order descending by 'total_count' would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I opened a [Facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/638370562885875?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52b09083be1ed6d65674385) for this issue.  Please encourage Facebook to fix it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

url is **indexable** column now. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

Have you used direct where clause to url?

```
SELECT url,
       normalized_url,
       share_count,
       like_count,
       comment_count,
       total_count,
       commentsbox_count,
       comments_fbid,
       click_count
FROM   link_stat
WHERE  url = "www.example.com";
```

Comment: The Facebook API docs say that this field is indexable but it doesn't seem to be when you try to use it in a query.  :(